# Android not in the main thread when using web sockets

Tags: android, websocket, google-maps-markers, okhttp, google-maps-api-2

I have an app where I have to use websockets to update markers on google map in real time. I successfully did the connection with web sockets and in the response I'm getting the json string. I parsed to JSONObject and when I debug I see that all the data in the json are coming but the problem is when I have to add markers. The error is:

```
e: "com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.c: Not on the main thread"
```

After connection to websocket I did the following code to get the data:

```
private OkHttpClient client;
    private EchoWebSocketListener webSocketListener;
    private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;

    public void startWebSocketConnection() {
        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

        webSocketListener = new EchoWebSocketListener(new EchoWebSocketListener.SocketClientListener() {

            @Override
            public void onConnected(WebSocket webSocket, okhttp3.Response response) {
                Log.d("Connected :", response.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void getMessage(String message) {
                Log.d("Received", message);
                List<ClusterItem> clusterItems = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(message).nextValue();
                    //String vehicle_id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                    String vehicle_class = jsonObject.getString("vehicle_class");
                    String kemlercode = jsonObject.getString("kemlercode");
                    String vehicle_speed = jsonObject.getString("vehicle_speed");

                    JSONObject newJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("portalMetadata");
                    String portal_id = newJsonObject.getString("id");
                    String portalName = newJsonObject.getString("portalName");
                    String location = newJsonObject.getString("location");
                    String[] coordinates = location.split(",");
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        double[] locations = Stream.of(coordinates).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
                        double latitude = locations[0];
                        double longitude = locations[1];
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);

                        Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                        cameraConfigurations(latLng);

                        ClusterItem loc = new ClusterItem(latitude, longitude, vehicle_class, kemlercode);

                        marker.remove();
                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                        clusterItems.add(loc);
                        mClusterManager.addItem(loc);

                        mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
                        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5.0f));
                        markers.add(marker);

                        setClusterManager(mClusterManager, clusterItems);
                        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, String reason) {
                Log.d("Failure :", reason);
            }

            @Override
            public void closingOrClosed(boolean isClosed, WebSocket webSocket, String reason, int code) {
                Log.d("ClosingOrClosed :", isClosed ? "Closed" : "closing");
            }
        });

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(SOCKET_URL).build();
        client.newWebSocket(request, webSocketListener);
    }
```

and I run the websocket in the runonuithread() on onCreate as in the following:

```
 runOnUiThread(this::startWebSocketConnection);
```

I'm using okHttp library to perform communications with websockets.
What I'm doing wrong here. Does anyone have any suggestion what I need to improve. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android does not allow network operations to be performed in the main UI thread. Use a worker thread instead.

Comment: Well, @RemyLebeau could you provide some more details please.

Comment: what more do you want me to say? Since Android 3, you cannot run network code on the main UI thread. Period. So you need to replace `runOnUiThread()` with a worker thread instead. I’m not going to get into the semantics of how to write multithreaded code, that is too broad a topic for a comment